# Who can you romance in Mass Effect: Andromeda?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

After playing for a while it seems that almost every character has a "heart" option (far left option), even some characters off the ship that I wouldn't have expected to be able to flirt with!

Are all of these romance options equal or are some of them just flings?

Who are you able to romance in Mass Effect: Andromeda, as each Ryder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this source](https://www.pcgamesn.com/mass-effect-andromeda/mass-effect-andromeda-romance-guide) (which seems consistent with other sources such as PC Gamer and [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#List_of_Characters_You_Can_Romance)), this is the list of characters with whom you can romance.

Edit: Added some known commitment requirements for certain NPCs.

- [Cora](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Cora_Harper) (Scott Ryder) - Commitment required.
- [Liam](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Liam_Kosta) (Sara Ryder) - No commitment.
- [Peebee](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Peebee) (Scott or Sara Ryder) - Commitment optional.
- [Jaal](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Jaal_Ama_Darav) (Sara Ryder) - Commitment required.
- [Vetra](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Vetra_Nyx) (Scott or Sara Ryder) - Commitment required.
- [Gil](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Gil_Brodie) (Scott Ryder)
- [Suvi](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Suvi_Anwar) (Sara Ryder)
- Reyes Vidal (Scott or Sara Ryder)
- [Keri T'Vessa](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Sex_and_Romance#Keri_T.27Vessa) (Scott or Sara Ryder) - No commitment.
- Avela Kjar (Scott Ryder)

**Notable:**

- You can flirt with Lexi T'Perro but they shut down either Ryder.
- Some crew members have flirtatious interactions with other crew
  members.

**Tips from the IGN guide:**

> "The way to romance characters is rather standard: flirt when you see
>   the heart icon, and if the character is interested, they'll convey
>   that to your chosen Ryder. Most will update their conversations after
>   you complete a major mission or character specific mission that'll
>   allow you to further your romance.
>
> Flirting with every character at the beginning doesn't hurt your
>   chances with the others later on."

**Also noted** about the romance system by the producer:

> "Ryder's personality is slowly set by those tones, with new
>   conversation options and character interactions unlocking when he or
>   she reaches different thresholds within those personality types."

Comment: Wait... that means I can't romance Suvi as male Ryder...? *sigh* Guess I'll start a new character then.

Comment: @Scorch91 Yeah unfortunately it does. She's the exclusive female to female, and Gil is the exclusive male to male.

Comment: Do you have any information on exclusivity? ie can you romance all of them in the same run through? Does romancing some shut down romancing others? Are some romances ignored by others?

Comment: @Chris I can add it along side them for the ones that had available information, but some are all about "no strings attached" flings, while some require commitment, and I don't believe you can commit to multiple people in one play through.

Comment: @n_palum: Thanks. I'd heard that at least Keri didn't care who else you were messing around with which led me to wonder who did and didn't care. Thanks for adding (sadly you already had my upvote).