# Can I continue romancing Peebee if I sleep with her after saving the Moshae?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I want to fully romance Peebee and am following a guide on this from [usgamer.net](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/16-08-2017-mass-effect-andromeda-how-to-romance-characters/how-to-romance-peebee). The guide mentions that you can sleep with Peebee the first time after bringing the Moshae back to Aya, but it's a bit vague on whether this choice affects any later romancing. The choice is between sleeping with her then or "wanting strings attached", which will take the relationship slower. Note: I'm not yet at this section. I've brought the Moshae back to Aya, but I only just picked up the first piece of Remnant Tech for Peebee.

If I sleep with Peebee, does that stop the romance questline, or can I continue it and sleep with her again later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sleep with PeeBee and continue to do so, so long as you're not fully committed to someone (Some relationships aren't full commitments). [See the romance guide.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304394/who-can-you-romance-in-mass-effect-andromeda?rq=1)

After finishing PeeBee's questline you'll eventually be able to fully engage in a relationship with her, but until then it's purely sleep with her when she is in the ship (should you so choose).

Comment: I was less wondering whether I'd be able to sleep with her again ("have zero-G daydreams") and more about whether sleeping with her instead of taking it slower would end in a situation like Jack from ME2 where sleeping with her when it's first possible ends the romance and you'd actually had to decline sleeping with her to continue the romance and get the eventual achievement for it.

Comment: Well in that case - you won't hurt the romance line with her at all if you have zero G daydreams.